# Image pagination with Carrierwave and Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, carrierwave

I'm attempting to paginate a series of photos using the Kaminari gem. The images are being displayed in the Dog model's show action, and the photos have been uploaded using CarrierWave to a separate model called DogPhoto. DogPhoto belongs to Dog, and Dog has many DogPhotos.

The Dog controller's show action looks like this (@dog is loaded in a before filter):

```
def show
  @dog_photos = @dog.dog_photos.page(params[:page]).per(1)
end
```

And the show view looks like this:

```
<div id="dog_photos">
  <% if @dog_photos.count > 0 %>
    <% @dog_photos.each do |dog_photo| %>
      <%= image_tag dog_photo.photo_url %>
    <% end %>
    <%= paginate @dog_photos %>
  <% else %>
    <%= image_tag("dog-with-no-photo.png", :border => false) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

When the page is loaded, the pagination links are displayed for the correct number of photos (one page per photo). However, only the first photo is displayed. When the user clicks on "2" it instead shows the dog-with-no-photo.png fallback image.

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the `.per(1)` code in your `show` action since it limits the number of pictures per page to only one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My aim is to display one photo per page. By removing the `.per(1)` it will display all of the photos a single page. The goal is to let the user browse through the photos one at a time by clicking `Next >>`.

Comment: Mea culpa. Did you try to invert the order of the `page` and `per` methods?

Comment: Inverting the methods throws up an `undefined method \`per'` error.